# Add new line at xml file with shell terminal

Tags: xml, shell, terminal

I have this part of XML file:

```
  <xs:complexType name="NioLocationRequest">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="tns:NioRequestBase">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="forceCreation" type="xs:boolean"/>
          <xs:element name="location" type="ns1:Location"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="roomZero" type="ns1:Room"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```

and I want to insert an 'xs:element' between "location" and "roomZero" with shell terminal (because the change would be done in many files).

So, I would like the result to be this:

```
  <xs:complexType name="NioLocationRequest">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="tns:NioRequestBase">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="forceCreation" type="xs:boolean"/>
          <xs:element name="location" type="ns1:Location"/>
          <xs:element name="replyTo" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="roomZero" type="ns1:Room"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Someone can answer, please? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), you can write

```
open file.xml ;
register-namespace xs http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema ;
for //xs:sequence {
    my $elem := insert element xs:element after xs:element[@name="location"] ;
    set $elem/@name "replyTo" ;
    set $elem/@type "xs:string" ;
    insert text {"\n        "} before $elem ;
}
save :b ;
```

To make it work over several files, you can add an outer loop:

```
for $file in { glob "*.xml" } {
    open $file ;
    ...
}
```